# Return type Overloading Operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-type

I have a questions, probably trivial...
There are restrictions on the return type with the overloading of operators?
I tried to overload operator +, in arguments I had two objects of class Nodo, and i wanted to return the sum of the attributes(with a get method), that were int.
So i write an external function `int operator+(Nodo a,Nodo b)` and this didn't work...So i tried with `int operator+(int tot,Nod a)` and this worked.
I suppose that the return type have to be one of the arguments?

```
class Nodo
{
    private:
        Nodo *Next;
        Employee *Emp;

    public:
        Nodo(){}
        Nodo(Nodo *a,Employee *b):Next(a),Emp(b){}
        virtual ~Nodo(){}
        void SetNext(Nodo *a){Next=a;};
        Nodo* GetNext(){return Next;}
        void SetEmployee(Employee *emp){Emp=emp;}
        Employee* GetEmployee(){return Emp;}
};

class Employee
{
    private:
        string name;
        int salary;

    public:
        Employee(string name,int salary):name(name),salary(salary){}
        virtual ~Employee() {}
        string GetName(){return name;}
        int GetSalary(){return salary;}
        virtual void PrintInfo(){cout<<"Nome "<<name<<" Salario "<<salary<<endl;}
};
```

I tried with

```
int operator+(Nodo a,Nodo b)
{
  int totale;
  totale=a.GetEmployee()->GetSalary()+b.GetEmployee()->GetSalary();
  return totale;
}
```

The result is the crash.

While this work.

```
int operator+(int tot,Nodo a)
{
  int totale;
  totale=tot+a.GetEmployee()->GetSalary();
  return totale;
}
```

Comment: `int operator+(Nodo a,Nodo b)` is possible.

Comment: " I suppose that the return type have to be one of the arguments?" - no, it doesn't.

Comment: In what way did it not work? Any specific error messages? Behavior that you didn't expect? Did it open a portal to eldritch abominations beyond space and time?

Comment: [Demo](https://ideone.com/kc7pxt)

Comment: Edit the question

Comment: So, what is the problem in my code? If there aren't limitations in the return type...

Answer (score 1):

There are rules for operator overloading regarding the **type** and **number** of arguments they can take.
For example:

1. Binary operators (such as `+`) declared as member functions take one
   argument; if declared as global functions, they take two arguments.
2. Overloaded operators cannot have default arguments.
3. The first argument for member-function overloaded operators is always
   of the class type of the object for which the operator is invoked
   (the class in which the operator is declared, or a class derived from
   that class). No conversions are supplied for the first argument.

But there are NO rules concerning the return type. So, you can return any type from an overloaded operator.